# BluetoothDevice getName() return null.

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

That I use android app to get the hardware's ble name ,but i can get the name that using iOS .I can't find any error of this. so what i should do for this issue.
here, i copy my code for looking .

> First:

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)     
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

> Next:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver,filter);
    // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver,filter);
```

> last:

```
     public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.e("走进receiver","bluetooth");
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already 
           if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
               String sname = device.getName();
           } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
      }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Hmm, you are doing a bluetooth scan. Maybe you should perform a BLE scan instead? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: Thinks for you comment......bluetooth scan with BLE scan , what's different of bluetooth scan and BLE scan.

Comment: It is more or less a substandard of Bluetooth for low energy purposes. If you want to have the ble name, I think you should perform a ble scan and not a BT scan.